# Regex for list of comma-separated floats

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to validate a form field in javascript (using bootstrap/jquery) but I need a regular expression which matches a string which is a comma separated list of numbers, there may or may not be spaces.

example:
1,2,3,3.14,6.0, -3.14, -6, 7.13,100

I can get the regex if they are all integers and no spaces in between, but having decimals really complicates things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try this:

```
^(\s*-?\d+(\.\d+)?)(\s*,\s*-?\d+(\.\d+)?)*$
```

```js
document.write(
    /^(\s*-?\d+(\.\d+)?)(\s*,\s*-?\d+(\.\d+)?)*$/.test(
        '1,2,3,3.14,6.0, -3.14, -6, 7.13,100'
    )
);
```

If you break up the above regex, you'll notice that it is capturing the first number in the string with:

```
(\s*-?\d+(\.\d+)?)
```

To capture the first number, it tries matching as many consecutive spaces `\s*` as necessary, followed by an optional hyphen (or negative sign) `-?`, followed by at least one numeric digit `\d+`, followed by an optional decimal point that has at least one consecutive numeric digit following the decimal point `(\.\d+)?`.

The next group captures all the numbers following the first one.

```
(\s*,\s*-?(\d+(\.\d+)?)*
```

is the same as the previous group except for an additional `\s*,` in front allowing for as many spaces as necessary `\s*` before matching a comma `,`. This group is repeated as many times as necessary `*`.

The regex starts with `^` and ends with `$` to make sure it starts matching from the beginning of the string `^` until the end of the string `$`.

Comment: That did it! I'm gonna have a field day trying to understand that one.

Comment: reduce `(\d+\.\d+)|\d+` to `\d+(?:\.\d+)?`

Answer (score 2):

If regex is not mandatory, then try this simple logic

```
function isValidInput(str)
{
   return str.split(",").filter(function(val){ return isNaN(val) }).length == 0;
}
isValidInput("1,2,3,3.14,6.0, -3.14, -6, 7.13,100");
```

Comment: Regex is mandatory, it is using pattern matching to match the value in the <input> field for validation.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate to @gurvinder372's answer, you can use `Array.every` instead of `Array.filter`. Benefit, it will not loop till the end and will break on first invalid entry. But, if you wish to get all incorrect values, then @gurvinder372's answer is preferred.

```js
function isValidInput(str) {
  return str.split(",").every(function(val) {
    return !isNaN(val);
  })
}
var test = isValidInput("1,2,3,3.14,6.0, -3.14, -6, 7.13,100");

alert(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
^(\s*(-|\+)?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s*,\s*)+(-|\+)?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s*$
```

Regex breakdown

```
^ ---> Starting of string
  (\s* ---> Match any number of white spaces
     (-|\+)? ---> Match - or + sign (optional)
     \d+ ---> Match digits before decimal
     (?:\.\d+)? ---> Non capturing group to match digits after decimal(optional)
     \s*,\s* ---> Match any number of spaces before and after comma
  )+ ---> Do this till last comma (or second last number)

  (-|\+)?\d+(?:\.\d+)? ---> Same as above but for checking only the last number as it should not have comma
  \s* ---> Check spaces after last number
$ ---> End of string
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/wT5jJ1/2)